# Generalização de parâmetros em Java

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, parâmetros, polimorfismo

Estou implementando uma árvore B para um trabalho de banco de dados em Java, de forma que esta guarde quaisquer tipos de objetos, seja genérica, assim estou tratando como se fosse `Object`, porém em alguns trechos de código preciso de métodos como `compareTo()`, que deverão ser implementados, porém a classe genérica não os fornece. Qual solução posso adotar?

Tenho o seguinte método:

```
public void add (Object o){

    Node aux = addRecursive (this.raiz, o); 

   ... 

}
```

Como obrigar que o parâmetro `Object o` tenha que implementar a interface `Comparable`.

Comment: Você pode também usar a classe `java.util.Objects` caso utilizar a interface `Comparable` ou `Comparator` não seja viável. Essa classe fornece métodos utilitários para objetos, veja esses métodos [aqui](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Objects.html).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Na verdade, não é possível fazer isso. Se precisa do método `CompareTo()` no objeto então tem que garantir que ele exista.

Até existe algumas gambiarras que podem ser feitas individualmente para poder usar classes que não possuem esse método, mas só seria útil em situação muito específica, não é viável como solução genérica.

A única solução é aceitar tipos que implementem o método, ou seja todos que tenham a interface [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Comparable.html).

Assim:

```
public void add(Comparable o) {
    Node aux = addRecursive(this.raiz, o); 
    ...
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Method/GeneralParameter.java).

Comment: Desculpe minha falta de conhecimento, mas como eu determino que o parâmetro tenha que implementar a dada interface

Comment: Depende, você não demonstrou como está querendo usar isto. A pergunta não tem detalhes, por isso a resposta também não tem.

Comment: Se sua classe não pode implementar a interface `Comparable`, você pode usar também a interface `Comparator`.

Answer (score 0):

Se o seu objetivo é criar uma arvore binária, tem de haver um fator de comparação entre os valores obrigatoriamente. Usando o tipo Object, realmente você poderá colecionar qualquer objeto Java, entretanto não é qualquer objeto que poderá ser comparado.

Uma solução seria usar uma interface como argumento, pois isso obriga que todos os objetos colecionados sejam "comparáveis entre si". Entretanto se você pensar bem, o cliente da sua classe vai precisar tomar um cuidado redobrado, pois se você colecionar objetos Comparáveis de tipos diferentes, você terá problemas.